# How can I debug this Spyder/Python code?

Tags: python, spyder, gurobi

Since I wrote this syntax as a variable in the spyde IDE/python and the error is

> invalid syntax

this is my code:

```
from gurobipy import*
try:
m = Model('operating_room')
#Data
b= [1,2,3]
n= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
j= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
t=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
W=0.5
m.update()
#create variables
X[j] =m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="X[j]")
Y[n] =m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="Y[n]")
x[b,j,t] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="x[b,j,t]") 
y[n,b] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="y[n,b]")
m.update()
#set objective
m.setObjective(quicksum(X[j] for j in J )+ W*(quicksum(Y[n] for n in 
N)),GRB.MINIMIZE)  #eqution 1

**for b in range(1,b):  
    #create constraints
    m.addConstr(quicksum(x[b,j,t]=1 for j in J for t in range(rb:(d[b]-
    p[b]+1))),name="block_allocation")    #eqution 2**
```

i need to know what's the problem in

```
    m.addConstr(quicksum(x[b,j,t]=1 for j in J for t in range(rb:(d[b]-
                                     ^
    p[b]+1))),name="block_allocation")    #eqution 2
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to get that line to do?

Comment: I want to make x (the patient) inserted to one block b and one operating room j and one time period t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x[b,j,t]=1` is a statement, not an expression. generator expressions cannot include statements.

If you really want to use a list comprehension instead of an ordinary `for` loop (which would probably be much clearer), you can `import operator` and use `operator.setitem(x, (b,j,t), 1)`.

Comment: thank you very much for your fast reply but please could you explain me how can i edit it since this statement is a constraint in my model